# Uncollected Rent

Tags: rent

I currently rent a plot of land that effectively extends my current garden. The garden is owned freehold and the plot is rented by me from a local land owner. In the past, the annual rent has been collected by the landowner submitting an invoice to me when payment fell due. The last anniversary was approximately six months ago and I have not received any claim for payment during this period. I was just wandering what the position would be if this situation continued for a long period of time, say a few years?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a rent agreement which says that you have the use of the land, and you pay some amount of rent every year. You most likely owe the money, whether you get invoiced or not. So I'd recommend paying the money into a savings account that you don't touch, to have the money when you are asked for it. (Say the landowner has gone senile, and in four years time he dies and the heirs want the money).

After long enough time, statute of limitations may come into effect. So you might not have to pay the seven year old debt, but only the last six years.